# loop/apply function to run two or more lists one by one

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

assume I have a user defined fun

```
fun <- function(i,j,k){}
```

I am looking for a function(), that

```
function(fun, c(x1, x2), c(y1,y2), c(z1,z2))
```

performs as

```
fun(x1,y1,z1)
fun(x1,y2,z1)
fun(x2,y1,z1)
fun(x2,y2,z1)    
fun(x1,y1,z2)
fun(x1,y2,z2)
fun(x2,y1,z2)
fun(x2,y2,z2)
```

I though apply family may do the job. However I did not find the right one.

=====================================================================

Here is a real example I am working on, however still cannot be solved.

```
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                   text = "ID x1 x2  y1  y2
                   1   a  T 100  2
                   2   b  T 210  4
                   3   b  F 112  5
                   4   a  F 121  1
                   5   b  F 412  1")

boxplot <- function(i,j){
  print(ggplot(data, 
               aes_string(x=colnames(data)[i], 
                   y=colnames(data)[j],
                   col=colnames(data)[i]))+
                 geom_boxplot())
}
```

then you can use `boxplot(2,4)` to make a plot, so does boxplot(3,4), boxplot(2,5), boxplot(3,5).

Then I tried both do.call and apply methods from answers.

```
do.call(boxplot, as.list(unname(expand.grid(c(2, 3), c(4,5)))))
```

or

```
apply(expand.grid(c(2,3), c(4,5)),1,boxplot)
```

however they did not work as expected.
the do.call method only returns one plot, and the apply one retures 8 plot but all have y axis as ID.

======================================================

the for loop made it work. Any comments?

```
for (i in 2:3) {
  for (j in 4:5) {
  boxplot(i,j)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sum3 <- function(x, y, z) x+y+z  # test function
mapply(sum3, 1:3, 11:13, 21:23)
## [1] 33 36 39
```

Here `sum3(1, 11, 21)` is 33, `sum3(2, 12, 22)` is 36 and `sum3(3, 13, 23)` is 39.  There are more examples on the `?mapply` help page.

This also works and returns a list:

```
Map(sum3, 1:3, 11:13, 21:23)
```

Comment: Actually, `mapply` is exactly what was asked. It passes distinct arguments, not a single vector. The `sum` function can accept any number of arguments.

Comment: Hi G thanks for your answer. My question may not be clear. The result I expect for your example would be a total of 9 sum3(), which go through all combinations of three numbers from three groups.

Comment: Hi G I added an example. Let me know if my question is clarified.

Answer (score 1):

xIt would be nice if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can verify possible solutions, but I think you can get what you want with `exapand.grid` and `do.call`. How about

```
do.call(fun, as.list(unname(expand.grid(c(x1, x2), c(y1,y2), c(z1,z2)))))
```

Do if you had

```
fun <- function(i,j,k){i+j+k}
x1<-1; x2<-2;
y1<-10; y2<-20;
z1<-100; z2<-200;
```

You would get

```
[1] 111 112 121 122 211 212 221 222
# x1+y1+z1, x2+y1+z1, x1+y2+z1, x2+y3+z1, ...
```

Comment: feels good to see that my reasoning somehow resonates with seasoned stack overflow members :)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Flick. You got a reproducible great example didn't ya ;)

Comment: Hi Mr. Flick I added an example to the question and your method does not quite work out. May you take a second look at it?

Comment: In your example, what corresponds to the vector of `x` and `y` values? I don't see two sources there. What are the exact series of functions calls that you want? Also, I assumed your function would be properly vectored but your example is not. That could be fixed by `Vectorize()` but it's unclear exactly what your desired output is. Normally you can only print one plot at a time without doing extra work,

Comment: I would like x to be column x1 and x2, and y to be column y1 and y2. And I would like to call them by assign i and j as the column numbers. With given data, column x1 and x2 would be refered by i = c(2,3), and column y1 and y2 would be refered by j=c(4,5). I hope this clarify the sources question. I will look into function vectorization. However, is there ways to produce multiple plots at once? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Mr. Flick I used a for loop to get what I want..   do not know how to format it in comments
for (i in 2:3) {
  for (j in 4:5) {
  print(ggplot(data, 
               aes_string(x=colnames(data)[i], 
                          y=colnames(data)[j],
                          col=colnames(data)[i]))+
          geom_boxplot())
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly,this should be pretty simple

```
apply(expand.grid(c(x1, x2), c(y1,y2), c(z1,z2)),1,fun)
```

edit : adding example

```
x <-c(13,14)
y <- c(21,22)
z<- c(35,36)
apply(expand.grid(x,y,z),1,mean)
[1] 23.00000 23.33333 23.33333 23.66667 23.33333 23.66667 23.66667 24.00000
```

Comment: glad that it helped .

Comment: Hi BG I added my real example to the question and the method doen not quite work out. May you take a second look at it?

Comment: I assume this has to do something with your boxplot function ,
you can only use functions which are vectorized like 'mean' in this .